# Access Django-Rest-Framework API from Swift Using Alamofire

Tags: django, swift, rest, django-rest-framework, alamofire

I hava a Django-Rest-Framework API and can access it using `curl` like so:

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/json; indent4' -u mrigdon:password123 http://localhost:8000/api/users/
```

and that works. I installed Alamofire in my Swift project and want to access the same endpoint using this code:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://localhost:8000/api/users", parameters: ["mrigdon":"password123"])
        .response { request, response, data, error in
            let jsonData: NSData = data!
            let jsonDict = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary
            print(jsonDict)
}
```

but get this 403 response:

```
detail = "Authentication credentials were not provided."
```

Anyone know how to properly format this Alamofire request?

Comment: How would your API throw that error? In what scenario? Also remember GET requests the parameters will be in the query string

Comment: The reason is because the user must be an admin to access that endpoint. Could you provide the format that it would be in?